# ADB command to wipe data the phone?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, factory-reset, odin

I have 200 Russian Phones to flash with UK Firmware. Now when i flash the UK firmware through Odin, it works fine but Russian firmware is still on it, however it does become UK if i factory reset the phone after that.

Now my question is that if there is any way where I don't have to factory reset the device and it automatically does it after Odin flash. That way I will save a lot of time.

I have tried these things:

- "adb --wipe_data", this doesn't work because I don't how to really send a command to Recovery.
- Cygwin terminal to break down firmware file into 4 file (AP, MODEM, BOOTLOADER and CSC). this doesn't work either.

Any help will be great. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try  this while the phones is on.

(You MUST have USB debugging enabled and authorized)

*adb shell recovery --wipe_data*

Comment: that is the problem, its time consuming. going into the phone and turning on USB debugging on each phone can take very long. its even longer than me doing factory reset manually. I need to come up with a way where somehow it automatically factory resets the phone or i can use some cmd magic. i hope this explains little bit more about my situation.

Comment: @Tarinder You can't use ADB without USB Debugging, and you asked for an ADB command.

Answer (score 2):

**The arguments which may be supplied in the recovery.command file:**

```
 *   --send_intent=anystring - write the text out to recovery.intent
 *   --update_package=path - verify install an OTA package file
 *   --wipe_data - erase user data (and cache), then reboot
 *   --wipe_cache - wipe cache (but not user data), then reboot
 *   --set_encrypted_filesystem=on|off - enables / diasables encrypted fs
```

You can take a look at here also:

[**Wipe data/Factory reset through ADB**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb)

Comment: yes, this is custom recovery i believe. i have seen this post, it somehow put me in right direction but in order for me to use adb, i have to enable USB debugging, which takes even longer than doing manual factory reset.

Answer (score -1):

*Source:* [Factory Resettin an Android Device from a Computer](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/factory-resetting-android-phone-computer-71407.html)

> **Step 7**
>   Turn on your Android phone and connect it to a USB port on your computer. Type “adb shell” and press “Enter.” When ADB connects to your device, type “--wipe_data” and press “Enter.” Your phone restarts in recovery mode and restores Android to factory settings.

But judging from your question the way you where doing the wipe command via adb was wrong.The way you where doing it was: "adb --wipe_data" where's you should try "adb shell" and then "--wipe_data"

A the list of arguments include:

> - The arguments which may be supplied in the recovery.command file: * --send_intent=anystring - write the text out to recovery.intent * --update_package=path - verify install an OTA package file * --wipe_data - erase user data (and cache), then reboot * --wipe_cache - wipe cache (but not user data), then reboot * --set_encrypted_filesystem=on|off - enables / diasables encrypted fs

*Source:*[Wipe data/factory reset through adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb)

Comment: does it need to have USB debugging "on" from the phone? or can i do this in downloading mode?

Comment: '--wipe_data' is not a shell command.